# Could I get the detail of error from qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Sometimes, I execute a circuit on the Quantum computing device (ex. ibmq_16_melbourne) and got error like 'Invalid job state. The job should be DONE but it is JobStatus.ERROR'. Could I get the detail of this error, such as the cause of a mistake or sth like that.

For this time, I try to execute a circuit that including

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, IBMQ, execute
from qiskit.visualization import *
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
IBMQ.load_account()
qr = QuantumRegister(6)
cr = ClassicalRegister(5)
mycir = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)
for i in range(13):
    mycir.mct([qr[0],qr[1],qr[2],qr[3]],qr[4],None, mode='noancilla')
    mycir.mct([qr[0],qr[1],qr[2]],qr[3],None, mode='noancilla')

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(group='open')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
job = execute(mycir, backend, shots=1000)
job_monitor(job)

result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()
# print(counts)
plot_histogram(counts, figsize=(14,8))
```

the result is error like above.

Comment: Hi! Could you share the qasm of your circuit?

Comment: Currently, I'm not sure about posting the whole circuit on the internet, but the circuit in edited post's detail shares the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this circuit through the transpiler, I get a circuit that has a depth of 2201. I imagine the reason this circuit won't run therefore is because it is too deep.

To remedy this I would suggest either reducing the depth of your circuit, or running it on a simulator with a noise model similar to the device you are trying to run it on.